# after trigger update statement take long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-trigger

I created a trigger as below

```
alter trigger sale_Trigger_Update on sale
after update
as
begin
Declare @old_value  varchar(50)
Declare @new_value varchar(50)
Declare @sale_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

DECLARE new_cur CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
        SELECT saleid
        FROM INSERTED

  open new_cur

          Fetch Next from new_cur into @sale_id
       while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        Begin
          set @old_value = (select enddate from deleted where SaleID = @sale_id)
          set @new_value = (select enddate  from inserted where SaleID = @sale_id)
          insert into zzz (old_value,new_value) values(@old_value,@new_value)
        end
         CLOSE new_cur
    DEALLOCATE new_cur

    end
```

Then I do an update statement as below

```
 update sale
    set enddate = null
```

`Sale` table contain only `2` rows

and the execution is  continuing unlimited.

I tried

```
update sale
set enddate = null
where saleid = 10
```

same problem.

Then I forcefully stopped the execution. Then checked the `sale` table and `zzz` table. No changes happened. 
I am sure there is some issue in cursor. Can somebody show some light on it.

****Edited****

Actually I need to check `enddate in deleted is null and enddate in inserted is not null`

```
open new_cur

              Fetch Next from new_cur into @sale_id
           while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            Begin
              set @old_value = (select enddate from deleted where SaleID = @sale_id)
              set @new_value = (select enddate  from inserted where SaleID = @sale_id)
            if @old_value = null and @new_value != null
            begin 
               SELECT approval.*,
(select diag.*
from diag diag 
where approval.id =diag.id
FOR XML PATH('diag'), TYPE
),
(select ser.*
from ser ser
where approval.id =ser.id
FOR XML PATH('ser'), TYPE
)
FROM approval approval,
where approval.id = 1
and approval.saleid =@saleid
FOR XML PATH, ELEMENTS,
root('Head')
            end if
            end
             CLOSE new_cur
        DEALLOCATE new_cur
```

Comment: When you say sale table contains only two rows, even with your cursor(which is not needed) it should not take that much time.did you check for any locking ,blocking

Comment: start by replacing that cursor with a simple join...

Comment: @mxix actually i need to take enddate from inserted and deleted to check some conditions.

Comment: @TheGameiswar no blocking..clueless :(

Comment: If you can add that to the question. Removing the cursor should be your top priority here.

Comment: Could you paste the estimated execution plan xml

Comment: @mxix edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the cursor.

Could you replace your trigger with?

```
alter trigger sale_Trigger_Update on sale
after update
as
begin

insert into zzz (old_value,new_value)
select
    --i.SalesID,
    d.enddate,
    i.enddate
from inserted i
inner join deleted d on
    i.SaleID = d.SaleID
where
    d.enddate is null and 
    i.enddate is not null
end
```

Comment: if d.enddate is null and i.enddate is no null i need to execute another query..for that particular saleid..thats why i used the cursor..

Comment: Could you add that to your question please ... you keep adding complexity =p

Comment: edited question..if the condition is correct i need to generate an xml for saleid..if two rows updated two xml file will generate

Comment: what do you do with that XML? Insert into another table? Just select it? why?

Comment: need to download that xml using programming

Comment: A trigger is not the best place to select things for "programming"... You should redo your logic within a Stored Procedure. With no Triggers. Take a look into OUTPUT to get the updated rows. Your problem is most likely the XML and not the insert. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107003/discussion-between-sachu-and-mxix).